# Connect Bluetooth module to PIC16F877A

Tags: pic

I have a PIC16F877A micro-controller. I need to interface a Bluetooth module with PIC. It will be connectted using UART Serial Communication. I have read the datasheet but couldn't find which exact module can be used with PIC.

Answer (score 1):

For a UART bluetooth module, there are loads of cheap ones available on eBay that will work with a PIC fine.
I have used the [HC-05](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Wireless-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-serial-RS232-TTL-HC-05-For-Arduino-/190872153566?pt=UK_Computing_Other_Computing_Networking&hash=item2c70ddedde) and the [JY-MCU](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Wireless-Serial-4-Pin-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-RS232-With-Backplane-Cable-/300912313706?pt=UK_Computing_Networking_SM&hash=item460fc5856a) modules without problems.

[image] [image]

The datasheets for the HC-05 are [here](ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/BLOG/2010_07/More_Powerful_Serial_Port_Bluetooth_Module_MasterSlave.pdf) and [here](http://elecfreaks.com/store/download/datasheet/Bluetooth/HC-0305%20serail%20module%20AT%20commamd%20set%20201104%20revised.pdf).